# ServiceStack default redirect not appending to URL

Tags: redirect, servicestack

I am having a small issue with servicestack where by when initialising the AppHost I want to give it a default redirect url, something like "/Home" as we dont have an index page on our site.

To do this I would assume you need to have the following:

```
Config.DefaultRedirectPath = "/Test";
```

However having just that redirects me to

```
http://Home
```

To have it redirect me to the actual page I want, ie: http://www.example.com/Home
It seems to only work when using:

```
Config.DefaultRedirectPath = "http://www.example.com/Home";
```

This would be ok except we want to have multiple url's take us to the same page, ie:
http://test.example.com/ and http://home.example.com/ should both go to http://www.example.com/Home

The site is hosted not hosted on the root as we have multiple servicestack sites running on the same machine.

Are there any settings that need to be changed or configured?

Answer (score 0):

[UrlMappings](http://www.dotnetperls.com/urlmappings) may help

```
    <urlMappings enabled="true">
        <add url="~/" mappedUrl="~/Home" />
    </urlMappings>
```